# jQuery $.AJAX to replace with JavaScript fetch - mvc4 method arguments are always null

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, promise, fetch

We had a working jQuery script which calls an MVC4 C# controller method like this:

```
// C# controller method
public ActionResult MyMethod(String text, String number) 
{
    ... do something ...
    ... returns a partial view html result ...
}

// javascript call
var myData = { text:"something", number: "12" };
$.ajax({ url:ourUrl, type:"GET", data: myData, 
       success: function(data) { processAjaxHtml( data )}});
```

Now we want to replace this $.ajax call to a native fetch(...) call like this (and use a Promise):

```
function startAjaxHtmlCall(url) {
     var result = fetch( url, {method: "GET", body: myData});
     return result.then( function(resp) { return resp.text(); });
}
starAjaxCall(ourUrl).then( resp => processAjaxHtml(resp) );
```

We have problems, and somehow we cannot find the answers:

- using GET we cannot attach body parameters (I see that the html GET and POST calls are quite different, but the $.ajax somehow resolved this problem)
- we changed the GET to POST but the controller method still got "null"-s in the parameters
- we changed the fetch call to "body: JSON.stringify(myData)" but the method still gots null
- we constructed a temp class with the 2 properties, changed the method parameters as well - but the properties still contains null
- we added to the [FromBody] attribute before the method class parameter but it got still nulls
- we replace body: JSON.stringify(myData) to body: myData - still the same

Note: we tried this in Firefox and Chrome, the code is MVC5, C#, .NET Framework 4.5 (not .CORE!) hosted by IIS.

We changed the javascript call as the following (and everything works again):

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: method,
        data: myData,
        success: function(data) { resolve(data); },
        error: function(error) { reject(error); },
    });
});

return promise;
    // note: .then( function(resp) { return resp.text(); }) // needs no more
```

So: what do we wrong? what is the information we do not know, do not understand about fetch? How to replace $.ajax to fetch in this situation correctly? can it works with GET again? how to modify the controller method to receive the arguments?

Comment: um, GET does not have a body

Comment: Can you show urlParams pls?

Comment: Ohh sorry, my mistake, same myData there as well. edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GET requests do not have a BODY, they have querystring parameters. Using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) makes it easy

```
var myData = { text:"something", number: "12" };
return fetch('https://example.com?' + new URLSearchParams(myData))
    .then( function(resp) { return resp.text(); })
```

Other way of building the URL

```
const url = new URL('https://example.com');
url.search = new URLSearchParams(myData).toString();
return fetch(url)...
```

If you were planning on sending JSON to the server with a post request

```
fetch('https://example.com', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(myData)
});
```

Comment: Just as an addition as the overall statement itself is not wrong: A `GET` request could have a body (at least from the perspective of the specification), but it would not make any sense to add one, because it does not have any semantic meaning for a `GET` request. In the best case, the body will be ignored, in the worst case the request it will be rejected.

Comment: You are perfectly right! Adding 'Content-Type': 'application/json' as header and the stringify() together works as a charm! Thank you! :)

Comment: And as a quick question: when the "url" already contains any ? part const url = new URL('https://example.com?id=12'); - then both of the construction methods are bad. Can you suggest any better solution?! thanks!

Comment: Seems odd you would mix them and the `id: 12` would not be in the object from the start. But `https://example.com?id=12&' + new URLSearchParams(myData)` work just fine.....

Comment: I am not sure if the "url" does not contains any ?id=12 part already. The general method must check it. Other problem, that when the url is generated in MVC cshtml as @Url.Action("myMethod","myController") then it does not contains any https://server part - so the new URL(url) wont accept it :( seems not so easy :(

Comment: So `+ new URLSearchParams(myData)` works fine.... If the server rejects new parameters, well than your original answer would not work since you were appending it to the query string....

Comment: Ohh. I see now. Sorry. :( Little bit tired.